# How do I describe plural things I saw?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which of these is correct?

> All I saw was flashes of lightning
>
> All I saw were flashes of lightning

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence seems fine to me. Since you are talking about a scene or an object that you have seen (not flashes of lightning), using a singular verb sounds more natural.

In other words, "All" here means "The only thing".

> The only thing I saw was flashes of lightning.

Answer (score 0):

There have been numerous questions about verbs that follow collective nouns and there are dozens of websites that address this issue. (Just google: singular or plural with collective nouns.)

The rule is that there isn't a rule. To some extent it depends on the collective noun concerned and on the context. Apart from that, some people prefer plural verbs and others go for singular verbs.

The guide is: If you think of what you're describing as a single event or amount or episode or phenomenon, prefer the singular.

If you think of them as multiple events etc, prefer the plural.

Thus it's equally valid to say:

> A million dollars is a lot of money

and

> A million dollars were scattered by the wind.

Another example, closer to yours, is:

> All I saw was people rushing in every direction

and

> > All I saw were people rushing in every direction.

The only rule is to be consistent:

Avoid sentences that mix up singulars and plurals such as: *The army says they are advancing* and *The train service are announcing its new schedule.